# How to create dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot data after putting them in a dictionary:

```
[('1547213806', '02141592cc00000005', '0'), ('1547213806', '02141592cc00000006', '0'), ('1547213806', '02141592cc00000003', '0'), ('1547213806', '02141592cc00000002', '0')]
```

I am using this function to create the dictionary:

```
def loadInfoFromLogFile(logFile):
    fsrc = open(logFile, 'r')
    buff = fsrc.read()
    fsrc.close()
    list_info = re.findall(data,buff)
    print(list_info)
    print(len(list_info))

    dict_node_info={}
    init_time = None
    for timestamp, id_src_node,Counter in list_info:
        if init_time == None:
            init_time = float(timestamp)
        #if id_src_node not in dict_node_info:
        #    dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time],
        #                              'Counter': [int(Counter)]}
        #else:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp) - init_time)
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(Counter))

    return dict_node_info
```

But I have this error while executing: `KeyError: '02141592cc00000005''`
If the condition IF is enabled (not commented), the function works correctly but It does not give me all `id_src_node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
     dictionary[key]
except:
     dictionary[key] = value
else:
     dictionary[key] += value
```

Comment: There’s a better way to do this. Use `dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, []) + value` assuming the item is a list.

Comment: ... or use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)